# Timezones validation regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to validate timezones. Example:

```
UTC-12
UTC-6:30
```

So - UTC will stay the same, sign will be alternating(+ or -) and number varies from -12 to +14.

I don't understand why this regex not working (I get not valid):

```
$val = 'UTC+12';
$range = '-11:30|-11|-10:30|-10|-9:30|-9|-8:30|-8|-7:30|-7|-6:30|-6|-5:30|-5|-4:30|-4|-3:30|-3|-2:30|-2|-1:30|-1|-0:30|\+0|\+0:30|\+1|\+1:30|\+2|\+2:30|\+3|\+3:30|\+4|\+4:30|\+5|\+5:30|\+5:45|\+6|\+6:30|\+7|\+7:30|\+8|\+8:30|\+8:45|\+9|\+9:30|\+10|\+10:30|\+11|\+11:30|\+12|\+12:45|\+13|\+13:45|\+14';

$regex = '/^UTC(\+|-)(' . $range . ')/';

    if(preg_match($regex, $val)){
        echo 'valid';
    }else{
        echo 'not valid';
    }
```

Comment: As for why it's not working, you're telling the regex to match for `UTC+-12 or UTC--12`. Now about that range variable... That's... not how you're supposed to use regex, to the best of my understanding. If you read some basic regex tutorials on matching time, they'll help you out.

Comment: @inTide: Your first sentence is the answer and should be posted as such, so we can upvote it

Comment: not sure if I follow you about range variable. These are the only valid UTC offsets. I can't have for example UTC-8:10. I could build that string from array with implode - what's the difference?

Comment: I meant instead of typing out every possible variable, a simpler `(\+|-)((1?[0-9](:30)?)|((5|8|12|13):45))` should match everything. @Daniel The reason I commented instead of answering was because I working (thinking) on something else and was just glancing at questions. I didn't provide the regex I mentioned so felt it wasn't really a complete answer, just a comment. Oh, I haven't tested that regex btw, I think I misplaced parentheses somewhere though, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @inTide: you're right. makes good sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` symbols in the regex so they are not greedy repeats.

for example, `+8` becomes `\+8`.  Something like this (php isn't my language):

```
$val = 'UTC+12'; $range = '-12|-11:30|-11|-10:30|-10|-9:30|-9|-8:30|-8|-7:30|-7|-6:30|-6|-5:30|-5|-4:30|-4|-3:30|-3|-2:30|-2|-1:30|-1|-0:30|+0|+0:30|+1|+1:30|+2|+2:30|+3|+3:30|+4|+4:30|+5|+5:30|+5:45|+6|+6:30|+7|+7:30|+8|+8:30|+8:45|+9|+9:30|+10|+10:30|+11|+11:30|+12|+12:45|+13|+13:45|+14';

$range = str_replace ( '+' , '\+' , $range)

$regex = '/^UTC(' . $range . ')/';

    if(preg_match($regex, $val)){
        echo 'valid';
    }else{
        echo 'not valid';
    }
```

Comment: thanks. this is how I had it in my php file. I guess I posted from incorrect example. I've updated the post - but still no dice.

Comment: `$regex = '/^UTC(' . $range . ')/';`  Also, your regex forced an extra sign `-` or `+`.  See updated answer.

Comment: @Andre: Please be aware of the fact that this is not the only thing agent-j changed. Have a look at the third line!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution behalf of the question author to move it into the answer space)*.

This was so simple. I forgot that I already use signs in my `$range` array. I don't even have to check for sign inside of my regex.

```
$regex = '/^UTC(' . $range . ')/';
```